# Log4Net regional/cultural settings

Tags: c#, log4net-configuration

How does one configure log4nets regional / culture info settings?

If I pass a date to the format methods it gets logged in US format, ignoring my application and o/s settings

```
log.InfoFormat("Invalid date of {0} found in field {1}", date, field.Name);
```

This writes out the date in month / date / year format which doesn't match my current culture into of date / month / year.

Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: You can try `date.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov yeah, I'd rather not have to manually specify the current culture everywhere I'm logging dates or other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally in log4net's default `ILog` implementation all of the calls of `InfoFormat`, `WarnFormat`, `DebugFormat`, etc. use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` if it was not specified explicitly (the methods have overloads). Which is kinda stupid since something like `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` would have been more correct, but what can we do.

So... You can specify your IFormatProvider of choice explicitly to have it used there. For example

```
log.InfoFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Invalid date of {0} found in field {1}", date, field.Name);
```

Or, alternatively, You can have this proxied in your own logger class that calls log4net logger object internally with the culture:

```
public static class Logger
{
    ...
    public static void InfoFormat(string pattern, params object[] values)
    {
        _log4net.InfoFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, pattern, values);
    }
```